# Access Nested JSON parameteres

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im trying to get the Vin part from the JSON array.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "vehicle": {
        "ownershipCondition": "Used",
        "registration": "BX68NHL",
        "vin": "ZFA3120000JA60541",
        "make": "Fiat",
        "model": "500",
        "generation": "Hatchback (2015 - )"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried using this but it doesnt work. Can anyone help.

```
foreach($result['results'] as $res)
{
    $currCar = $res['vehicle']['vin'];
    echo $currCar."\n";
}
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: @aynber It doesnt show anything. Also in the logs I get errors like Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'results'

Comment: You have to [decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) it first. The dupe question will help you out.